# How to Change Background-Color on my Fixed Navigation Menus when Scrolling Using Waypoints(JS ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jquery-waypoints

Im trying to change the background-color of my navigation menus(navbar) when someone scrolls it using waypoints. Problem was, it didn't work. Because "I think", its because of the video tutorial I watched which is outdated? Or there seems to be a problem with my code? I reviewed the code 10 times, like I almost had a crossed-eye vision.

Here is the final code of the video tutorial I watched.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import waypoints from '../../../../node_modules/waypoints/lib/noframework.waypoints';

class StickyHeader {
    constructor() {
        this.siteHeader = $(".site-header");
        this.headerTriggerElement = $(".large-hero__title");
        this.createHeaderWaypoint();
    }

    createHeaderWaypoint() {
        var that = this;
        new Waypoint({
            element: this.headerTriggerElement,
            handler: function() {
                that.siteHeader.addClass("site-header--dark");
            }
        });
    }
}

export default StickyHeader;
```

[image]

I would really appreciate if someone could help me.
And here is my App.js

```
import MobileMenu from './modules/MobileMenu';
import RevealOnScroll from './modules/RevealOnScroll';
import $ from 'jquery';
import StickyHeader from './modules/StickyHeader';

var mobileMenu = new MobileMenu();
var revealOnScroll($(".feature-item"), "85%");
var revealOnScroll($(".testimonial"), "60%");
var stickyHeader = new StickyHeader();
```

Comment: You haven't stated your issue. Please update your question and try to be as descriptive as possible.

Comment: Sorry for that @EmielZuurbier. Hold on a sec.

Comment: There you go @EmielZuurbier.

Comment: Great! Have you created an instance of `StickyHeader()` somewhere and are you encountering errors in the console?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Yes! I just updated it already to be more specific.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I dont encounter any errors/problems in the browser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are combining jQuery with a version of Waypoints.js that is not meant to work with jQuery.

At the moment you are selecting elements with jQuery, which will give you a result in the form of a jQuery object

```
$(".site-header");
// This will result in:
{
  0: <div class=".site-header">...</div>
}
```

But the `element` property on the `Waypoint` constructor expects an element instead of an object. So you could either select the elements with Vanilla JavaScript using [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Also use `classList.add` instead of `addClass` since you are now dealing with pure JS elements instead of jQuery objects.

```
import waypoints from '../../../../node_modules/waypoints/lib/noframework.waypoints';

class StickyHeader {
    constructor() {
        this.siteHeader = document.querySelector('.site-header');
        this.headerTriggerElement = document.querySelector('.large-hero__title');
        this.createHeaderWaypoint();
    }

    createHeaderWaypoint() {
        var that = this;
        new Waypoint({
            element: this.headerTriggerElement,
            handler: function() {
                that.siteHeader.classList.add("site-header--dark");
            }
        });
    }
}

export default StickyHeader;
```

Or use the jQuery variant of the framework and use it like this.

```
var $siteHeader = $(".site-header");
var $headerTriggerElement = $(".large-hero__title");

$headerTriggerElement.waypoint({
  handler: function() {
    $siteHeader.addClass("site-header--dark");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to scrap the waypoints plugin, you can do this with vanilla javascript just using `getBoundingClientRect` of each element.

```js
class StickyHeader {
  constructor() {
    var that = this;
    this.siteHeader = document.querySelector(".site-header");
    this.headerTriggerElement = document.querySelector(".large-hero__title");
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      that.createHeaderWaypoint();
    });
  }

  createHeaderWaypoint() {
    var that = this;
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

    var headPosition = this.siteHeader.getBoundingClientRect();
    var screenPosition = this.headerTriggerElement.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (headPosition.bottom >= screenPosition.top) {
      this.siteHeader.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      this.siteHeader.classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
}

temp = new StickyHeader();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100px;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.site-header {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.large-hero__title {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1400px 0;
}

.site-header.active {
  background: black
}
```

```html
<div class="site-header">header</div>
<div class="large-hero__title">hero!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it seems I'd copy-paste the code and turns out it didnt work. My mistake I guess? And the .site-header class is the parent of .large-hero__title.